# Obj-C NSLog a buffer

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

I have got the following function which I am trying to print the dataIn out to NSLog,

```
some_function (const void *dataIn, size_t dataInLength)
{
    NSMutableString *in1 = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i=0; i<dataInLength; i++)
        [in1 appendFormat:@"%02x", dataIn[i]];
}
```

This is my current code, however upon compilation I get "error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'const void'"

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a couple of casts:

```
void some_function (const void *dataIn, size_t dataInLength)
{
    const char *cdata = (const char *)dataIn;
    NSMutableString *in1 = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i=0; i<dataInLength; i++)
        [in1 appendFormat:@"%02x", (unsigned)cdata[i]];
}
```

The first is so `[i]` knows how many bytes to offset into the buffer (`sizeof(char)` is known) and secondly casting to `unsigned` as that's what printf-formatting expects the size of the `%x` specifier values to be (you probably don't actually *need* this one, but I'm fussy).

Answer (score 0):

Change `const void *dataIn` to `const char *dataIn` or try casting it on

```
[in1 appendFormat:@"%02x", (char) dataIn[i]];
```

Comment: what if dataIn has to remain as const void?